# How to send someone to a contact form with predefined select option chosen

Tags: html, forms, select, contacts

Apologies for the confusing title, if I knew an efficient and simple way to put it, I would've googled it and I wouldn't be in this situation in the first place :)

I have a "nice and simple contact form" consisting of:
Name,
Subject,
Message.

The subject is a drop down list with 3 options:

```
<select>
<option value="x">X</option>
<option value="y">Y</option>
<option value="z">Z</option>
</select>
```

I have another page with contact links: "click here to contact me about X", "click here to contact me about Y", "click here to contact me about Z". All of them pointing towards the above mentioned contact form.

What i'd like to achieve is that, when a visitor clicks "click here to contact me about Y", the page will send the visitor to the contact form, but have the Y subject automatically selected.

Does that make sense?
What would be the simplest way to achieve that?

Thank you :)

Comment: I did not understood your question but I guess [Query String](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) is what you are searching for... [W3C URI recommendation](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/4_URI_Recommentations.html)

Comment: You're absolutely right! thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use **`selected="selected"`**

#### HTML

```
<select>
    <option value="x">X</option>
    <option value="y" selected="selected">Y</option>
    <option value="z">Z</option>
</select>
```

Check this <kbd>**[demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3eMAH/)**</kbd>

this demo example default selected **`Y` option`**.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd also like the other links to point towards their specific select fields also, when one clicks "contact me for X" to have the X option automatically selected, same for "Z"

Comment: you have to selected item acces into another page you want to use dynamic language which dynamic language you use php, python ruby ?

Comment: I wasn't kidding when I said "nice and simple contact form", that's the actual name of the form: css-tricks.com/examples/NiceSimpleContactForm/ It has a very basic contactengine.php file

Comment: ok so you use php lang. ok so you want to selected value get into another page

Answer (score 0):

You need to send that value from previous page to this page.
For eg. http://mydomain.com/current_page?my_param=X
Now you have to extract this param from url, and set that value into your select box

```
var myParam = location.search.split('myParam=')[1];
if(myParam){
  $("select").value(myParam);
}
```